# Is there documented evidence of Israel concentration/death camps used against the Arabs?

Tags: israel, palestine, death, 1940s, conquest

According to some articles I've been reading, there is testimony that as Israel began its conquest and subsequent occupation of Palestine, they sent Arab men to concentration, labor and even death camps.

Here's just one example of such an article, from [Palestine Remembered](http://www.palestineremembered.com/Articles/General/Story1649.html).

I am looking for more sources regarding the Israeli Death camps for a report I am doing for Israel Apartheid Week 2015 and I am having trouble finding good documentation online and sifting through the noise.

Did the early Israel/Zionist army document its concentration camps like the Nazis before them did, or perhaps did any other national agency or organization document them? If yes, where can I find such documentation? If not, why not?

I appreciate all your help. May God bless you.

Comment: You are reading political propaganda instead of history. To begin with, Israel never "began its conquest" of Palestne. And occupation if it was the result of the Arab (unsuccessful) attempt to conquest Israel.

Comment: Your question asserts that the Israeli army did in fact have concentration camps, and only asks whether or not they were documented.  As such it really can't be answered.

Comment: The article that you link to does not claim that there were death camps. There is only a caption to a photo that reads, "Note the absence of men, most likely they were sent to labor or concentration camps." Whatever the truth of that statement might be, [concentration camps](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Concentration_camps&redirect=no) are not [death camps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extermination_camp).

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is a valid question, even if you have a different view of history

Comment: "Everyone is entitled to his own opinion, but not his own facts." - Daniel Patrick Moynihan.

Comment: No. But I doublt Curious1 will be back to hear it. On the other hand, that close reason sucks.

Answer (score 6):

There was Atlit Detainee Camp, a prison built by the British to hold Jewish immigrants. POWs from the Arab armies as well as Palestinian irregular forces were put there but all were released shortly after the war's end in 1949. Contrary to the wishes of the organizers of Israel Apartheid week,it was not an extermination/torture camp. For a few years after the war, however, Arabs in mostly Arab areas were under military administration but were transitioned to regular civilian administration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wasn't asking about British camps for Jews, I was asking about Jewish camps for Arabs

Comment: @Curious1 your misunderstanding him, he said it was originally built by the british for the jews, however, the jews were using it to hold arabs, because the times hes given means that it would have already been given over to the jews.